# Pandas: Get values from column that appear more than X times

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame in pandas and would like to get all the values of a certain column that appear more than X times. I know this should be easy but somehow I am not getting anywhere with my current attempts.

Here is an example:

```
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame([{"uid": 0, "mi":1}, {"uid": 0, "mi":2}, {"uid": 0, "mi":1}, {"uid": 0, "mi":1}])
>>> df2

    mi  uid
0    1   0
1    2   0
2    1   0
3    1   0
```

Now supposed I want to get all values from column "mi" that appear more than 2 times, the result should be

```
>>> <fancy query>
array([1])
```

I have tried a couple of things with groupby and count but I always end up with a series with the values and their respective counts but don't know how to extract the values that have count more than X from that:

```
>>> df2.groupby('mi').mi.count() > 2
mi
1      True
2     False
dtype: bool
```

But how can I use this now to get the values of mi that are true?

Any hints appreciated :)

Answer (score 34):

Or how about this:

Create the table:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame([{"uid": 0, "mi":1}, {"uid": 0, "mi":2}, {"uid": 0, "mi":1}, {"uid": 0, "mi":1}])
```

Get the counts of each occurance:

```
>>> vc = df2.mi.value_counts()
>>> print vc
1    3
2    1
```

Print out those that occur more than 2 times:

```
>>> print vc[vc > 2].index[0]
1
```

Comment: Cool that works! Not the most elegant way I guess as it returns an index but if I wrap the selection in `np.array` it does the job: `np.array(vc[vc > 2].index)`. Thanks!

Comment: No need to create a new array, the index object holds an array, vc[vc > 2].index.values returns array([1])

Comment: NOTE: value `value_counts` is much slower than `counts()`

Comment: This solution prints out only the first of the elements though, as specified by the index. If there are more than one values fulfilling the condition, they will not be printed out!

Comment: Is there a more functional way of having. `vc = df2.mi.value_counts(); vc[vc > 2]` without having to define a separate `vc` variable?

Comment: Like somehow doing `df2.mi.value_counts()[self>2]`?

Answer (score 21):

Similar to @nicolaskruchten, slightly shorter version

```
 df2.mi.value_counts().loc[lambda x: x>5].reset_index()['index']
```

And if you don't need to have the result within a serie, just do this:

```
df2.mi.value_counts().loc[lambda x: x>5].index
```

Comment: Excellent. I haz been lookz for thiz 4 long time.

Comment: This is an amazing solution, using `loc` with `value_counts()`

Answer (score 18):

I use this:

```
 df2.mi.value_counts().reset_index(name="count").query("count > 5")["index"]
```

The part before `query()` gives me a data frame with two columns: `index` and `count`. The `query()` filters on `count` and then we pull out the values.

Comment: This is the fastest and the best answer!!

Comment: Nice one. Have a look to my answer, might interest you too :) @nicolaskruchten

Answer (score 9):

I found a problem with the solution provided by @juniper-
If there are more than 2 values fulfilling your condition, they will not be printed out. For example:

```
>>> check=pd.DataFrame({'YOB':[1991,1992,1993,1991,1995,1994,1992,1991]})

>>>vc = check.YOB.value_counts()
>>>vc
1991    3
1992    2
1995    1
1994    1
1993    1
Name: YOB, dtype: int64
```

Let's say we want to find years which appear more than once:

```
>>>vc[vc>1]
1991    3
1992    2
Name: YOB, dtype: int64
```

If we now want to access the actual value, we need to do:

```
>>>vc[vc>1].index.tolist()
[1991,1992]
```

Rather than call it by index, which will print out the first value only:

```
>>>vc[vc>1].index[0]
1991
```

Comment: nice vectorized solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(df2.mi)
df2[df2.mi.isin([key for key in counts if counts[key] > 2])]
```