# Find the count of unique values in dataframe pandas ie) value occured only once in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Can someone help me how I can find a count of values that have occurred only once in a column in a pandas dataframe? I know we can use n number of functions like `nunique` or `unique().size` and so on but they give us only the count of distinct values whereas I am trying to find values that hva occurred only once in an entire column. Here is an example

```
import pandas as pd
technologies = {
    'Courses':["Spark","PySpark","Python","Pandas","Python","Spark","Pandas","AWS","Spark"],
    'Fee' :[20000,25000,22000,30000,25000,20000,30000,50000,20000],
    'Duration':['30days','40days','35days','50days','40days','30days','50days','90days','30days'],
    'Discount':[1000,2300,1200,2000,2300,1000,2000,1500,1000]
              }
df = pd.DataFrame(technologies)
```

Running `df.Discount.unique().size` will be value `5` which are `[1000, 2300, 1200, 2000, 1500]`

But my intended output is `2` which are `[1200, 1500]`

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: Get values from column that appear more than X times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22320356/pandas-get-values-from-column-that-appear-more-than-x-times). I'm pretty sure all the answers to this post will work if you cahnge `>` by `==`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html) returns a Series. Just count how many values have only one count:

```
counts = df.Discount.value_counts()
counts[counts==1].sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
df = df.groupby('Discount').count()['Courses'] 
df[df==1]

Discount
1200    1
1500    1
Name: Courses, dtype: int64
```

EDIT:
See answer of Ignatius Reilly, using `value_counts` is better.

Comment: thank you @JarroVGIT. Yours is good as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html#pandas.Series.duplicated) with `keep=False`, inverse the boolean with `~` and [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
df.apply(lambda s: ~s.duplicated(keep=False)).sum()
```

Output:

```
Courses     2
Fee         2
Duration    2
Discount    2
dtype: int64
```

If you want the values:

```
(df.mask(df.apply(lambda s: s.duplicated(keep=False)))
   .stack().groupby(level=1).agg(list)
)
```

Output:

```
Courses         [PySpark, AWS]
Discount      [1200.0, 1500.0]
Duration      [35days, 90days]
Fee         [22000.0, 50000.0]
dtype: object
```